# android-how to save a view to sd card

Tags: android, bitmap

i have a imageview , i am trying to save bitmap from imageview  by  this method

```java
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
```

the rgb of saved image is not like that it looks in running app,so i am wondering if there is any way to save image view directly to a sd card rather getting the bitmap and then save it to sd card.
please help me i have tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write object using below code :

```
public static void witeObjectToFile(Context context, Object object, String filename)
{
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = null;
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = context.openFileOutput(filename, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objectOut.writeObject(object);
        fileOut.getFD().sync();

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (objectOut != null)
        {
            try
            {
                objectOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // do nowt
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Object readObjectFromFile(Context context, String filename)
{
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    Object object = null;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileIn = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
        objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        object = objectIn.readObject();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // Do nothing
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (objectIn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                objectIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // do nowt
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

For example ArrayList can be saved as :

```
ImageView abcImage = (ImageView) readObjectFromFile(context, AppConstants.FILE_PATH_TO_DATA);
```

and write as :

```
witeObjectToFile(context, abcImage, AppConstants.FILE_PATH_TO_DATA);
```

Comment: @thanks for helping me.. but i am getting exception  objectOut.writeObject(object);
 although  i am feeding it to imageview.in 
witeObjectToFile(getApplicationContext, pencilImage, "Test.jpg");

Comment: What exception you are getting? please share the log

Comment: i have imageview in my xml so i am not using readObjectFromFile(,)..so i am feeding that imageview to your witeObjectToFile() method
and exception is caught in catch block of the method which shows E/3(21554): android.widget.ImageView when i print e.getMessage();

Comment: Use "e.printStackTrace()" instead of e.getMessage() for getting crash log.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSaveImage) {
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        storeImage(bm);
    }
}

private boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData) {

    // get path to external storage (SD card)
    String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourappname/";
    File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);

    // create storage directories, if they don't exist
    sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

    try {
        File file = new File(sdIconStorageDir.toString() + File.separator + "fileName");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        imageData.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.getPath() },
                new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Snapshot Saved to " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```